# How to conatenate the contents of files in directory to a single file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to concatenate the contents of files available in directory to a single master file. Where in the each content should be spaced along with the file name.

```
import os
import time
import glob


# List avaialbe directory
for dir in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isdir(dir):
        print("The available directories are \t" + dir)

# ChangeDirectory
        os.chdir(dir)
        for file in glob.glob("*.sql"):
            # print("The files are: " + file)
            readFiles = open(file, 'r').read()
            print("the files are", file)
            masterFile = open('Master.sql', 'w')
        for fileContents in readFiles:
            masterFile.write(str(fileContents))
        masterFile.close()

print("Closing in 1sec")
time.sleep(1)
```

I expect the master file should contain the contents of each file present in directory and in master file the contents of each file should be spaced with the file names

Comment: You've told us what you expect. You've not told us what happens instead.

Comment: you have to use "a" (append) instead of "w" (write). Or open master file only once - before loop - and close after loop.

Comment: Sorry for that. When I run this code, Only 1 file contents is getting copied.

Comment: `masterFile.write(readFiles.read())` without `for`-loop - but use `readFiles = open(..)` without `read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open master file before loop and close after loop.

Open readFile without `read()

```
readFile = open(filename, 'r')
```

but use `read()` in

```
masterFile.write(readFile.read())
```

I'm not sure if it will need '\n' at the end

```
masterFile.write(readFile.read() + '\n')
```

To add file name use

```
masterFile.write(filename + '\n')
```

---

`dir` and `file` are reserved words so I use `dirname` and `filename`

---

```
import os
import time
import glob

masterFile = open('Master.sql', 'w')

for dirname in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isdir(dirname):

        print("directory:", dirname)
        os.chdir(dirname)

        for filename in glob.glob("*.sql"):

            print("filename:", filename)
            masterFile.write(filename + '\n')

            readFile = open(filename, 'r')
            masterFile.write(readFile.read())
            #masterFile.write(readFile.read() + '\n')
            readFile.close()

masterFile.close()

print("Closing in 1sec")
time.sleep(1)
```

---

The same using `with` so it doesn't need `close()`

```
import os
import time
import glob

with open('Master.sql', 'w') as masterFile:

    for dirname in os.listdir('.'):
        if os.path.isdir(dirname):

            print("directory:", dirname)
            os.chdir(dirname)

            for filename in glob.glob("*.sql"):

                print("filename:", filename)
                masterFile.write(filename + '\n')

                with open(filename, 'r') as readFile:
                    masterFile.write(readFiles.read())
                    #masterFile.write(readFiles.read() + '\n')

print("Closing in 1sec")
time.sleep(1)
```

---

**EDIT:** for two started folders "A" and "B". But as before it check sql in subfolders of started folder, but not directly in started folder.

```
import os
import time
import glob

home_dir = os.getcwd()

with open('Master.sql', 'w') as masterFile:

for start_dir in ['A', 'B']:

    # go to directory
    os.chdir(start_dir)

    for dirname in os.listdir('.'):
        if os.path.isdir(dirname):

            print("directory:", dirname)
            os.chdir(dirname)

            for filename in glob.glob("*.sql"):

                print("filename:", filename)
                masterFile.write('--' + filename + '\n\n')

                with open(filename, 'r') as readFile:
                    masterFile.write(readFiles.read())
                    #masterFile.write(readFiles.read() + '\n')

    # go back
    os.chdir(home_dir)

print("Closing in 1sec")
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Assume, there are two directory 'A' and 'B'. Directory A has 3 .sql files and Directory B has 4 sql files. 
 1. Directory A 
      |-- SQL1.sql
      |-- SQL2.sql
      |-- SQL3.sql
 2. Directory B
      |-- SQL1.sql
   |-- SQL2.sql
   |-- SQL3.sql
   |-- SQL4.sql

I am looking to create a MasterSQL in each directory that is 'A' and 'B'. When I run the above code, Master.sql gets created in Directory A but NOT in Directory B. 

2. And also in this  `masterFile.write(filename + '\n\n')` I need the file name to be commented or prefixed with '--' (Ex. --SQL1.sql)

Comment: `masterFile.write('--' + filename + '\n\n')`

Comment: more or less: `for start_dir in ["A", "B"]: os.chdir(start_dir) ; for dirname in os.listdir('.'):` For absolute paths to "A", "B"  it can be all. For relative path It would need remeber folder in which program started and move back to this folder before `chdir(start_dir)`. I add code to asnwer - it will be more readable then in comment.